# Listening to object keys in Zustand

Tags: reactjs, zustand

In Zustand, how can I listen to changes for a specific object key only?

In this case, I want my `useEffect` to trigger only if `parent.childA` is changed, but not if `parent.ChildB` is changed. I currently get an infinite loop.

Given a state like this:

```
export const useMyStore = create<IMyState>((set, get) => ({
    parent: {
        childA: "Lorem",
        childB: false,
    },
}));
```

And a React component like this:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
    const [parent] = useMyStore((state) => [parent]);

    // I want this useEffect to be triggered
    // only if parent.childA is changed
    useEffect(() => {

        // I want to be able to update parent.childB here,
        // without it triggering this useEffect again.

    }, [parent]);
};
```

How do people usually go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You are gonna have go use Immer (I believe) but you might just get by with using proper depndency in the useEffect.

From the zustand middlware. Noted here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zustand-updating-draft-states-advanced-demo-3znqzk

But, I am curious about your destructuring. Maybe start there. Your useEffect will always run because the object will always be a new reference. I'd just use [parent.childA] as the dependency.

Have you tried something like:

```
const [childA] = useMyStore((state) => [state.parent.childA]);
or
const childA = useMyStore((state) => state.parent.childA);
```

And just use childA as the dependency in the useEffect.